# Github - syncing a fork after updating a branch

Tags: git, github

I'm sure someone will be eager to mark this as a duplicate, and maybe so, but please read first as I'm still learning github.

I've forked a project, I have a local repo on Windows with origin pointing to my fork and upstream pointing to the original project. Using the command line editor, I've created a local branch with my updates, let's call it my 'feature branch', and pushed that branch to the origin (my fork). Since pushing the feature branch the upstream (original project) has been updated, so on the default/master branch I've done a pull and then a push. My fork's master now says it is even, but my fork's feature branch is many commits behind.

How should I update my feature branch, local and remote, **without losing my changes**? I've read the following but still confused/not sure:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork

[github pull upstream and remote not updating files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147025/github-pull-upstream-and-remote-not-updating-files)

[Github, pulling/updating from upstream after forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358052/github-pulling-updating-from-upstream-after-forking)

My newbie thinkiing suggests I need to somehow move the branch to the top of the tree.

Comment: Go to feature branch, 'git fetch upstream master ' and then 'get rebase upstream/master' and then force push that to your feature remote branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **rebase** the `feature` branch onto the updated `master` branch.

```sh
### Usage
# rebase current/active branch onto master
git rebase master

# OR, do a rebasing without checking out the branch you want to rebase
# rebase branch "feature" onto branch "master"
git rebase master feature
```

After that, force push the rebased `feature` branch to remote branch `origin/feature`, cause the history is changed on branch `feature`.

```sh
git checkout feature
git push origin feature --force
```

#### Example

Here's an example: rebasing branch `experiment` onto `master`.

Before:

[image]

Rebasing: take the patch of the change that was introduced in `C4` and **reapply** it on top of `C3`.

```
$ git checkout experiment
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: added staged command
```

After:

[image]

#### References

- [Rebasing from book *Pro Git*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: Many thanks @Simba for your clear easy to follow instructions and the reference article link, it worked!! If already checked out the feature branch, and after doing `git rebase master` is it strictly necessary to then do `git rebase master feature', the response was `Current branch feature is up to date`.

Comment: @NickW Sorry, I didn't make it clean. You don't need to run `git rebase master feature` after one time rebase. The command is used to exemplify you can rebase the `feature` branch to `master` branch without checking out the `feature` branch.